# How to return the index of multi value field in the search results in Lucene?

Tags: lucene

I have a document that contains `tags` field, I add it like this:

```
for (Tag tag : tags) { //rock, disco, jazz
   fields.add(new StringField("Tag", tag.name, Field.Store.YES))
}
```

Now, when I perform the search I would like to get not only document that has a tag, but also specific index within the `Tag` field that matches the query.
For, example, now when I search for `jazz` I need also within search results `index=2`. To know exact tag that was matched (because I use also prefix search and phrase search).

How can I achieve that with Lucene?

Comment: My approach was to get the set of term vectors from `reader.getTermVector(hit.doc, "field_name")`. That allowed me to access the offsets & indexes for all terms in the matched document. But then I had to iterate over those terms to locate the required offset for the one specific search term. As Dmitry pointed out, this is double-work. I do not know how to select the one required term, directly, as part of the search results.

Comment: Your example is also a way to go. However, I simplified the question and actual search for the tag is more complex, so iterating and searching again within every matched documents is not an option.